# How to solve this super hard star-creatiing problem?

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to creates stars from the first line increasing until they are the same as the number. then from there they will decrease until the star left is only one!

```cpp
#include<iostream>
    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float number;
    int i, j, k, m, n, control1 = 0, control2 = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    
    for(i = 0;i <= (number/2) + 2; ++i)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for(j = 0;j < control1; j++) //tengoh
        {
            cout << "*";

        }
        control1 += 1;
    }
    control2 = control1;
    for(m = 0;m < number; ++m)
    {
        cout << "\n";

    for(n = (control1 - 1);n < control2; n++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        control2 += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us an example of the expected input and output ?

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: ah its okay now I'm capable of doing this question, thanks for helping out though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float number;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < number; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= j; ++i) {
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < number - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = number - 1; i > j; i--) {
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output with input `10`:

```
Please enter a number:10

*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, i = 1;
    std::cin >> number;

    while (i <= number)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            std::cout<< "*";
    
        std::cout << std::endl;
        i++;
    }

    number -= 1;
    
    while (number > 0)
    {
        for (int j = number; j > 0; j--)
            std::cout << "*";
    
        std::cout << std::endl;
        number--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add text to the answer. The idea of SO is to explain things. Helpful for the guy asking the question would be what he did wrong.